# How can I achieve layout bigger than Screen size viewable on swipe

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view, swipe

I am trying to create a xml layout which can be sometime bigger than screen's width may be even height. As I will be adding table in xml so there can be a situation that layout width and height exceeds screen's width and height. I tried to figure out with following code-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shaby.payshare.WorkPageOneFragment">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What happened here exactly is that extra portion in the view gets hidden.
But what I wanted is to see that view that got hidden and have similar control over it as in entire view when I swipe in that direction which presently is not possible. Is it possible to achieve? If yes how can I get through it?

**Important**
ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView is there but they work in one direction either up and down or left and right.
I want all direction swipe smoothly.

All I am doing inside a fragment.

Comment: use horizontalscrollview

Comment: will it help both ways i meant swipe down, up, left right all ways

Comment: You can use horizonal scrollview for this like this

Comment: for that you might need to create a ScrollView nested inside a HorizontalScrollView @Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala

Comment: Isnt there any other other way round? Something more good.

Comment: what do you mean by "more good"?

Comment: I meant that was a common way which I too thought of. I wanted some new tricks newer. Anyway I got some hint. Thanks.

Comment: then wait for someone else to answer your query who can teach you newer tricks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/bot_scoreBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/table_shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <TextView />
        more than 16 columns of made using TextView
 ....
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to swipe in all direction then this library would be very helpful for you https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

Comment: Yes I can use this but it will help me only left and right. I forget to mention I want all way swipe in all possible direction.

Comment: Ok then i think this library would be helpful for you https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

Comment: Thanks that is a great help.

Comment: No privilege yet.

Comment: you will have the privilege of upvote because you have asked this question and you can accept my answer i ll edit it.